# Where is the control board in my furnace?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I want to install a Nest thermostat into my home and realized I didn't have a C wire and it was recommended to install a Google Nest power connector. The installation seemed simple so I got one. When I opened my furnace I had trouble finding the circuit board.

So I was wondering if someone can help me locate it or if there just isn't one in my furnace because I've heard the older ones tend not to have one. I took these photos to see if it can help but if more photos are needed please ask and I'll be happy to provide them.

This is a picture of the top. It's blurry but its basically instructions on what to do if it needs to be removed or worked on. When I took this photo I was wondering if it could be on top because it looked like it can be removed but didn't try it because I didn't want to mess with it.

[image: outside of furnace]

[image: inside of furnace, but not where the electronics are]

This is a photo of the inside of the bottom like I said before I couldn't find it anywhere so I don't know if this helps but I can take other photos if needed.

Comment: That top panel should also lift off revealing the circuit board.

Comment: Can you get us the make and model of your furnace please?

Comment: Can you get us photos of the inside of the junction box headed off the far left of your second picture?

Comment: Actually guys ended up opening the top and was able to find what I was looking for. Gonna install nest later today. I’ll let you guys know how it goes. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

The thermostat wire will enter the unit's housing somewhere.

Find that and then remove whatever panels you need to in order to trace that wire on the inside of the unit.  Follow that wire to the control board.